# Page-wise JPEG conversion/export from PDF using Ghostscript on Windows

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, ghostscript

I would like to use **ghostscript** to **convert** the **pdf** source into series of **jpeg** images. Everything works fine except:

- The format specifiers (%d) for .jpeg output file names are not working on
  Windows (I am using Windows 7 64bit), so I need to call gswin64c.exe as for every single page.
- The exported .jpeg files have white stripes around the page, while .pdf
  does not have anything there – can I get somehow rid of them?

My command line:

```
gswin64c.exe \
   -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE \
   -sDEVICE=jpeg \
   -r350 \
   -dJPEGQ=100 \
   -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 \
   -sOutputFile=magazine-1.jpg \
     magazine.pdf
```

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) sample PDF page exhibiting this behavior? Without a sample it's not possible to tell for sure the cause of your white strips, nor to show a way to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Windows, you have to double the `%` character for the format specifier to get the page number increment:

   ```
   gswin64c.exe \
        -o magazine-page_%%04d.jpg \
        -sDEVICE=jpeg \
        -r350 \
        -dJPEGQ=100 \
         magazine.pdf
   ```
2. Without seeing your PDF, I cannot tell for sure where your white strips come from.

   So, just theorizing: Usually, what appears in PDF pages (viewed in a PDF reader or printed on paper) as a white background in reality is a *transparent* background. (You can make transparent areas visible in Acrobat Reader: go to *Preferences...*  -> *Page display* and activate the checkbox *Show transparency grid*.

   JPEG does not know about transparency and converts all fully transparent areas to white.

   You could trim the white areas off with the help of ImageMagick. Or, if you know the exact widths of each of the strips (and the PDF page dimensions), you could tell Ghostscript via additional commandline parameters to trim away these...

   You could also convert to PNG, which supports transparency:

   ```
   gswin64c.exe \
        -o magazine-page_%%04d.png \
        -sDEVICE=pngalpha \
        -r350 \
         magazine.pdf
   ```

   Note, that there will still be stripes around the page image -- however they will be transparent instead of white.

Comment: Most likely the white borders are the difference between the mediabox (which GS uses) and the CropBox (which viewers use). You can use -dUseCropBox to tell GS to use the CropBox instead of the MediaBox. You shouldn't need toe double the '%' *unless* you are calling GS from a batch file, on the command line '%d' should work just fine. A sample PDF ilfe, version of GS being used, would help